# ¿Como puedo realizar esta petición sin JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo esta petición con `JQuery`, pero me gustaría realizar el `request` sin esta `librería`. Gracias.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://randomuser.me/api',
    //data : { id : 123 },
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(json) {
        console.log(json.info);
    },
    error : function(xhr, status) {
        alert('Fallo');
    },
    complete : function(xhr, status) {
        alert('OK');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```js
function getUsers() { 
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //URL de tu API
    x.open('GET', 'https://randomuser.me/api', true);
    x.send();
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
            var JSONdata = JSON.parse(x.responseText);
            console.log(JSONdata);
        }
    }
}
getUsers();
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo también con la API `fetch` que es nativa del navegador y tiene excelente soporte, quedando de este modo; mediante el uso de promises para manejar las eventuales respuestas de la petición

```js
let url = 'https://randomuser.me/api'

fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Del mismo modo para manejar los errores que se pueden presentar al momento de hacer tus peticiones lo haces con `catch()` quedando de este modo

```
let url = 'https://randomuser.me/api'

fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => console.log(data))
          .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

**CON ASYNC Y AWAIT**

Te puede quedar de este modo

```js
    async function getData(){
      const response = fetch('https://randomuser.me/api')
      const dataGiven = await response;
      const final = await dataGiven.json()
      console.log(final)
    }
    
    getData()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Creación de la petición HTTP
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Petición HTTP GET asíncrona si el tercer parámetro es "true" o no se especifica
req.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/imagenes", true);
// Gestor del evento que indica el final de la petición (la respuesta se ha recibido)
req.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // La petición ha tenido éxito
  if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
      console.log(req.responseText);
  } else {
    // Se muestran informaciones sobre el problema ocasionado durante el tratamiento de la petición
    console.error(req.status + " " + req.statusText);
  }
});
// Gestor del evento que indica que la petición no ha podido llegar al servidor
req.addEventListener("error", function(){
  console.error("Error de red"); // Error de conexión
});
// Envío de la petición
req.send(null);
```

La petición al servidor puede tener éxito, pero es posible también que se produzca algún error en la respuesta como por ejemplo, que no se encuentre la información solicitada. Para ello, se verifica que la propiedad status de la petición contenga los valores que aseguran que la respuesta ha tenido éxito.

Se distinguen dos casos de error principales:

La petición no ha alcanzado el servidor (nombre del servidor incorrecto, error de conexión, etc.). Estos errores activan el evento de tipo  error  sobre la petición. El gestor asociado muestra el mensaje "Error de red" en la consola.

La petición ha recibido una respuesta del servidor, pero el procesamiento de la información ha fallado (problema interno del servidor, recurso no encontrado, etc.). Es el retorno de la petición, a través de la propiedad  status  la que indica el resultado. Un código mayor o igual que 200 y menor que 400 marca que la respuesta ha tenido éxito.

**Escribir una función AJAX genérica**

Si tu programa necesita realizar varias peticiones HTTP hay que evitarla duplicación de código, haciendo una función que se encargue de esta tarea. Las únicas variaciones de la función serán la URL del servidor al que enviar la petición, y la acción a realizar una vez obtenida la respuesta.

```
function ajaxGet(url, callback) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", url, true);
  req.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
      // Llamada ala función callback pasándole la respuesta
      callback(req.responseText);
    } else {
      console.error(req.status + " " + req.statusText);
    }
  });
  req.addEventListener("error", function(){
    console.error("Error de red");
  });
  req.send(null);
}
```

**La función  ajaxGet  permite ejecutar una petición HTTP asíncrona.**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar fetch,como se muestra a continuación:

```js
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api')
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson) {
  console.log(myJson);
});
```

Fetch es compatible con las siguientes versiones de browsers
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Visita la documentación oficial
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch